# How to remove top level from svn dump file

Tags: svn, svnadmin, svndump

I have an svn dump file which includes the name of the repository in all the paths. i.e
    repo/trunk
    repo/branches
    repo/tags
I am using the dump file to recreate the repo on another server, but I need to remove "repo" from the path otherwise I get an error when I am trying to load.

The svn documentation online says to hand edit the file but when I do that I get checksum errors during loading. There must be a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have an svn dump file which includes the name of the repository in
>   all the paths. i.e repo/trunk repo/branches repo/tags

The dump does not include the name of the repository. It should include only paths that this repository contains. I guess that this is not the repo's name, but a name of the project.

> The svn documentation online says to hand edit the file but when I do
>   that I get checksum errors during loading. There must be a better way
>   to do this?

You could `svn move` the parent dir to the root of the new repository after loading the dump. The command should be as follows:

[`svn move FROM-URL TO-URL -m "ENTER LOG MESSAGE"`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.move.html)

PS Modifying dump files manually is possible and should work. However, this is a non-trivial task and I'd recommend that you avoid it unless you have some special case.